# Files in Depot not visible in Workspace

Tags: perforce

Perforce P4V for Windows:

I can see some files in the depot that aren't in my workspace even though that directory is included in the workspace tree. I tried to 'get latest revision' but that didn't fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check your workspace mapping. There might be some exclusions with '-' at the beginning. It might be to also check if you have any P4IGNORE settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your workspace's contents relative to the depot are defined by your `View`.  Check the view to see if it includes the depot files in question.

If you're using streams, then the view is generated by the stream the workspace is bound to; check the stream's `Paths` and its `Parent` if applicable.